# FLask : submitting different actions with a dynamically generated form

Tags: python, flask

I am building a basic Flask application with a sqlite database.

The feature I am having trouble implementing is for a user to be able to accept or refuse a contact request (like a friend request) from another user.

On the "/contacts" page, you can see all the contact requests you received from other users without problem, but I want to add the option to accept or refuse them and this is where I'm stuck.

A form is dynamically generated by fetching from the database all the contact requests the current user has received and displaying them on the page.

I have tried using two `<input type="submit" name="accept/delete" value="id_of_the_request">` tags for each requests, one with the accept option, the other with the delete option, both leading to the same route, but unlike some other input types, the "value" property controls what text appears on the button, so I can't set that to, say, the id of the contact request (which I did in the code further below) because then I see two buttons with a number on my page.

I thought about doing the opposite and setting the `name` of the tag to the request's id instead, and the `value` to "delete" or "accept", but then on the server side I wouldn't know what name to get with `request.form.get()` since the request's id are dynamically generated in the form depending on what's in the database.

I feel like I'm missing some basic knowledge and that it shouldn't be too hard to do that though.

Here is my html code (the template is passed a list of dictionaries (requests) from the database, corresponding to the list of contact requests received by the current user. Each request consists of 3 columns : request_id, user_email, contact_email. request_id is the primary key, user_email is the email of the person who sent the request, while contact_email is the email of the person who received it. ):

```
<form action="/manage_requests" method="post">
  <ul>
    {% for request in requests %}
      <li>{{request.user_email}} sent you a contact request.</li>
      <input type="submit" name="accept" value="{{request.r_id}}">
      <input type="submit" name="refuse" value="{{request.r_id}}">
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</form>
```

Here is my python code to handle accepting or refusing the request :

```
@app.route("/manage_requests", methods = ["POST"])
@login_required
def manage_requests():

    acceptedID = int(request.form.get("accept"))
    refusedID = int(request.form.get("refuse"))
    
    ## Add the user who sent the request as a contact for both them and us, then delete the request.
    if acceptedID :
        # fetch the info of the request corresponding id from the database requests table 

        # get the sender's user_email

        # insert the data into the database contacts table for both the sender and the receiver (current user)

        # delete the request from the requests table in the database

        return redirect("/contacts")
        
    ## Delete the request
    elif refusedID :
        # delete the request from the database requests table

        return redirect("/contacts")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would have done it:

First a route that returns all contact requests like you did:

```
@app.route("/contacts", methods = ["POST"])
@login_required
def contacts():
   # requests_list = Find all the requests for a user 
   return render_template('contacts.html', requests_list=requests_list)
```

Then I return in my template all the requests found:

```
<ul>
  {% for request in requests %}
      <li>{{request.user_email}} sent you a contact request.</li>
      <a href="{{ url_for('manage_requests', request_id=request.r_id, action='accept' )}}">
          <input type="submit" name="accept">
      </a>
      <a href="{{ url_for('manage_requests', request_id=request.r_id, action='refuse' )}}">
          <input type="submit" name="refuse">
      </a>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Note how I use the `<a></a>` tag around the submit button, with the **Jinja2** `url_for` function passed to the `href` attribute, with the `request_id` as a parameter and a variable `action` which takes as the value either `accept` or `refuse`:

And finally:

```
@app.route("/manage_requests", methods = ["POST"])
@login_required
def manage_requests():
    action = request.args.get('action')
    request_id = int(request.args.get('request_id'))
    
    ## Add the user who sent the request as a contact for both them and us, then delete the request.
    if action == "accept" :
        # fetch the info of the request corresponding id from the database requests table 

        # get the sender's user_email

        # insert the data into the database contacts table for both the sender and the receiver (current user)

        # delete the request from the requests table in the database

        return redirect("/contacts")
        
    ## Delete the request
    else :
        # delete the request from the database requests table

        return redirect("/contacts")
```

Comment: Alas  it doesn't work with the POST method of my /manage_requests route, I tried using your code in a ``` <form>``` instead of a ```<a>``` like so :

```<form action="{{ url_for('manage_requests', request_id=request.r_id, action='accept' )}}" method="post"><input type="submit" name="accept" value="accept"></form>

and using ```request.form.get``` in the manage_requests route, but the route isn't receiving the extra data ("action" and "request_id") passed to url_for.
Any idea ?

Comment: Alright I have solved my problem, thanks a lot for your help, there wasn't much left to do after what you suggested, so I replaced the `<a>` tag with `<form>` as mentioned above, but in order to receive the extra arguments action and request_id on the server side, they have to be included in the route like so : `@app.route("/manage_requests/<request_id>/<action>", methods = ["POST"])
@login_required
def manage_requests(request_id, action):`

instead of using `request.form.get()`

It is now working perfectly ! Thanks a lot for your help :D